# How to attach Mpdf output as email attachment with Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, email, mpdf

In my controller generating pdf layout and then attaching it as Pdf and with a custom filename. Here is the code

```
$this->load->library('mpdf');
$mpdf = new Mpdf('L', 'A4', 0, 'Trebuchet MS', 6, 6, 9, 9, 3, 3, 'L');
ob_start();
echo $this->generateFoodReport($inspectionId);
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$mpdf->WriteHTML(utf8_encode($html));
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($mpdf->Output('', 'S')));
$filename = "inspection-report.pdf";

$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->set_mailtype("html");
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->from($fromMail, $fromName);
$this->email->to($mailTo);
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->attach($content):
$this->email->send();
```

How to attach the file with email.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Send plain PDF buffer to the mail class.

```
$content = $mpdf->Output('', 'S');
$this->email->attach($content, 'attachment', $filename, 'application/pdf');
```

See [Email Class Codeigniter documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#CI_Email::attach).

Comment: This work in Laravel 8 also with FDPF and FPDI.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
$this->load->library('mpdf');
$mpdf = new Mpdf('L', 'A4', 0, 'Trebuchet MS', 6, 6, 9, 9, 3, 3, 'L');
ob_start();
echo $this->generateFoodReport($inspectionId);
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$mpdf->WriteHTML(utf8_encode($html));
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($mpdf->Output('', 'S')));
$filename = "inspection-report.pdf";

$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->set_mailtype("html");
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->from($fromMail, $fromName);
$this->email->to($mailTo);
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->attach($content, 'attachment', $filename, 'application/pdf');
$this->email->send();
```

For more please check [Codeigniter Email Class documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#CI_Email::attach)

Comment: Email sent successfully with attachment but the pdf contains error - not opening. Showing damaged file.